# How to read and store speaker notes from PowerPoint presentation file

Tags: c#, powerpoint

How to read and store speaker notes from PowerPoint presentation file that is stored in my hard drive location?

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint;

Application PowerPoint_App = new Application();
Presentations multi_presentations = PowerPoint_App.Presentations;
Presentation presentation = multi_presentations.Open(@"D:\Peak Sourcing\Work\ppt_test\presenting.ppt");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each slide in the presentation's Slides collection has a NotePage member.
The NotesPage is basically a separate slide with all the same collections and methods.  Here's a VBA function that will return the notes text from a slide:

```
Function NotesText(oSl As Slide) As String

    Dim oSh As Shape
    
    For Each oSh In oSl.NotesPage.Shapes
        If oSh.Type = msoPlaceholder Then
            If oSh.PlaceholderFormat.Type = ppPlaceholderBody Then
                If oSh.TextFrame.HasText Then
                    NotesText = oSh.TextFrame.TextRange.Text
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next

End Function
```